# AngularJS passing a parameter in an $http.get() to get a subset of a json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am currently stubbing my $http.get() calls with json files.  I am wanting to return a subset of the json file to angular controller.  I have looked at other post and they suggested setting a params property in the Get call but it is not working for me.

Here is my controller:

```
 angular.module('agileApp')
.controller('projectController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $filter, $http, $routeParams){

$http.get('json/testData.json').success(function(data){

    //console.log(data);
    $scope.projectData = $filter('filter')(data.projectDetail, {Id:1})[0];
    console.log($scope.projectData);
});

}]);
```

Here is my json file:

```
{ 'projectDetail': [{
    'Id': 1,
    'projectName': 'Project1',
    'projectStatus': 'In Progress',
    'teamMembers': ['User1,'User2', 'User3'],
    'userStories': [
        {'userStoryId': 0,
         'Description': 'As a user blah blah blah 1',
         'storyPoints': 10
        },
        {'userStoryId': 1,
         'Description': 'As a user blah blah blah 2',
         'storyPoints': 10
        },
        {'userStoryId': 2,
         'Description': 'As a user blah blah blah 3',
         'storyPoints': 10
        },
        {'userStoryId': 3,
         'Description': 'As a user blah blah blah 4',
         'storyPoints': 10
        },
        {'userStoryId': 4,
         'Description': 'As a user blah blah blah 5',
         'storyPoints': 10
        },
        {'userStoryId': 5,
         'Description': 'As a user blah blah blah 6',
         'storyPoints': 10
        },
    ]
},
```

There are other objects in the project detail array, but I just want to pull back the one where Id = routeID which is passed into the controller as a parameter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: From my comprehension, params is just a parameter you send to the webservice, so if you don't process it to do something or if you just have a json, you will get that json. I would go one of two ways here, first a method in your controller or preferably a service that will parse the JSON to return what you need. Or use the $httpProvider to process it before it returns [$http doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your json is invalid, so $http.get gives you a string instead of an object

There are some syntax errors and overmore angular requires proper quotation (different to js in common).

> [I testet a simple set with this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9f7Vbxnl4dClAkN96TQO)

Here is my simplified json. I think you can easily figure out how to adopt yours. (It's " intead of ')

```
{
  "projectDetail": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "projectName": "Test1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am still however having trouble parsing the data.  I've updated my question with my filter code, but it is returning undefined.

Comment: is data of the success function null? did you check if success is ever called? Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: i think because its invalid angular fails to give you an object. instead data is a string. so its not null. but you can't access like data.projectDetail, because it's just a string.